# IE9 + Browser is not submitting the form in IE9, but works fine for IE7, IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, browser, internet-explorer-9

In my Rails application, when i try to submit a form from IE7 or IE8. It works as expected. But when I try from IE9, it fails.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Took me a little while to resolve this, but it's actually down to a bug in IE9 by the looks of it.
If you have a `<p>` tag before your form, make sure you close it with `</p>` before you get to the `<form>` tag.

Basically, closing a `<p>` tag is optional, and it should be automatically closed by a block level element such as the `<form>` tag.
Unfortunately IE9 is not closing it. However, if you then have a block level element in your form (such as a `<div>`), the `<p>` will automatically close at that point.
The form then becomes a child element of the `<p>` tag, and the div element (along with your form controls and submit button) drops out of the form altogether.

This is bad:

```
<p> <form> <div> Form Contents </div> </form>
```

which is rendered in IE9 as:

```
<p> <form> </form> </p> <div> Form Contents </div>
```

This is good:

```
<p></p> <form> <div> Form Contents </div> </form>
```

I can only seem to replicate the problem when using scripting to modify the `innerHTML`, but as far as I understand this is a general bug with the `<form>` element within IE9.
Personally, I would recommend closing ALL `<p>` tags manually to avoid any problems like this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: More info available here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692565/ie9-bug-with-optional-p-close