# Form CSS not working on IE9 only?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-9

My testing link is jcleung.com/m2g-test/

For some reason, the styling I have on my form is working on every browser (inclduing lower versions of IE) except for IE9!

Anybody else have this issue of know a fix?

[image]

Comment: In IE9, the `<form>` element is not present in the DOM.

Comment: What's not working? Please provide a screenshot. The form displays exactly the same for me on Chrome (latest) and IE10 and it's compatibility mode of IE9, 8 and 7.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply...can you explain that to me please?

Comment: Works fine on here as well, did you try to force empty caches etc.?

Comment: I can confirm that this is a real problem: on IE 10 (Win 7), the form is styled (e.g., the button has white text on cyan background), but when the “document mode” is set to IE 9, it is unstyled.

Comment: I did empty the cache and it is still not working.  The solution posted below regarding changing the meta is not working either...thanks for all the responses BTW

Comment: Re the observation of @ŠimeVidas: on IE 10 in IE 9 mode, the `form` element is there (when studied in Developer Tools, F12), but as a child of `p` (where is should not appear of course). This might break styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have some validation errors that may be worth fixing.

Secondly, for some reason the  element (on which you target your CSS) doesn't contain all the fields in ie9:

[image: IE9 Console]

You have your `<form>` wrapped with `<p>` tag and I wonder if that makes it go crazy? Anyway, I'm pretty sure it's a html bug and I'll keep you updated if I find the problem.

EDIT:

Ok, I did some tests and I'm 99.9% sure it's because the form is wrapped with  p

Comment: THANKS!  taking away the <p> tags did the trick!  I wonder why that is?  I did it just for the default padding and margins.  Perhaps it made the elements become in-line in IE9?

Comment: No worries! I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692565/ie9-bug-with-optional-p-close

Comment: The form is not wrapped within a `p` element. Markup like `<p><form ...>` is valid (except in XHTML) and means that there is an empty `p` element before the form. But IE 9 gets this wrong, as noted (and removing the `<p>` tag is the best solution – any desired vertical spacing can be achieved by setting CSS properties on the `form` element).

Comment: It's not wrapped any more because that was the problem... Look at the link I posted above. HTML5 allows all crazy nesting but apparently IE9 doesn't like this particular one, even though it's a HTML5 document